# E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored...” when tunning “sudo aptitude update”?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, updates, aptitude

This is what the end of output after I run `sudo apt-get update` on Ubuntu 12.04:

```
35% [Working]W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/eclipse-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/eclipse-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/eclipse-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

My version of Ubuntu is 12.04.

**Update:**

I figured out dates with this command

`find /etc/apt -name '*.list' -exec bash -c 'echo -e "\n$1\n"; cat -n "$1"' _ '{}' \;`

Here is output:

/etc/apt/sources.list

```
 1  #############################################################
 2  ################### OFFICIAL UBUNTU REPOS ###################
 3  #############################################################
 4  
 5  ###### Ubuntu Main Repos
 6  deb http://mirror.mirohost.net/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe multiverse
 7  deb-src http://mirror.mirohost.net/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe multiverse
 8  
 9  ###### Ubuntu Update Repos
10  deb http://mirror.mirohost.net/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted universe multiverse
11  deb http://mirror.mirohost.net/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse
12  deb http://mirror.mirohost.net/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
13  deb-src http://mirror.mirohost.net/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted universe multiverse
14  deb-src http://mirror.mirohost.net/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse
15  deb-src http://mirror.mirohost.net/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
16  
17  ###### Ubuntu Partner Repo
18  # deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
19  # deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
20  
21  ###### Ubuntu Extras Repo
22  # deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
23  # deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
24  # deb http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu precise main
25  # deb-src http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu precise main
```

/etc/apt/source.list

```
 1  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main universe
```

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-y-ppa-manager-precise.list

```
 1  # deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu precise main
 2  # deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu precise main
```

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-talkplugin.list

```
 1  ### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
 2  # You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
 3  deb http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/ stable main
```

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list

```
 1  # deb http://deb.playonlinux.com/ quantal main
```

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/private-ppa.launchpad.net_commercial-ppa-uploaders_intellij-idea-ce_ubuntu.list

```
 1  # deb https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/intellij-idea-ce/ubuntu precise main #Added by software-center; credentials stored in /etc/apt/auth.conf
 2  deb https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/intellij-idea-ce/ubuntu precise main #Added by software-center; credentials stored in /etc/apt/auth.conf
```

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-sublime-text-3-precise.list

```
 1  # deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu precise main
 2  deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu precise main
```

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/typesafe-apt.list

```
 1  # Typesafe repository.
 2  deb http://apt.typesafe.com/ unicorn main # Typesafe "unicorn" releases.
```

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/eclipse-team-ppa-precise.list

```
 1  deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/eclipse-team/ppa/ubuntu precise main
 2  deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/eclipse-team/ppa/ubuntu precise main
```

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list

```
 1  ## Please report any bug on https://bugs.launchpad.net/medibuntu/
 2  deb http://packages.medibuntu.org/ precise free non-free #Medibuntu - Ubuntu 12.04 "precise pangolin"
 3  # deb-src http://packages.medibuntu.org/ precise free non-free #Medibuntu (source) - Ubuntu 12.04 "precise pangolin"
```

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/lezhoev-qstamina-precise.list

```
 1  deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/lezhoev/qstamina/ubuntu precise main
 2  deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/lezhoev/qstamina/ubuntu precise main
```

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java-precise.list

```
 1  deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu precise main
 2  deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu precise main
```

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/tualatrix-ppa-precise.list

```
 1  deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu precise main
 2  deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu precise main
```

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kilian-f_lux-precise.list

```
 1  deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kilian/f.lux/ubuntu precise main
 2  deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/kilian/f.lux/ubuntu precise main
```

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-wine-ppa-precise.list

```
 1  deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu precise main
 2  deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu precise main
```

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/fsqcds-goldendict-precise.list

```
 1  deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/fsqcds/goldendict/ubuntu precise main
 2  deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/fsqcds/goldendict/ubuntu precise main
```

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-rhythmbox-precise.list

```
 1  deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/rhythmbox/ubuntu precise main
 2  deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/rhythmbox/ubuntu precise main
```

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/upubuntu-com-devel-precise.list

```
 1  deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/devel/ubuntu precise main
 2  deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/devel/ubuntu precise main
```

And I caught another snippet of trouble  at `sudo apt-get update`:

```
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                                                        
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages                                                 
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                                                  
  404  Not Found
```

- ***How to solve this trouble?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as the first bunch of 404 errors is concerned, it seems that `http://ppa.launchpad.net/eclipse-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise` does not exist (you mention it in your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/eclipse-team-ppa-precise.list`).  I reckon you don't need this anymore, as the eclipse platform is included in the standard Ubuntu repositories.

The second bunch of 404 errors cannot be explained, unless you have other source lists that you didn't include here.

Comment: Have to solve this trouble? Can you explain more?

Comment: Remove the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/eclipse-team-ppa-precise.list` or comment out its contents.